# Iterate hash based on condition

Tags: ruby

```
colors = [
  ["blue","red","green"],
  ["yellow","red","green"],
  ["orange","red"]
]

elements =[
  {"sun"=>"yellow"},
  {"sky"=>"blue"},
  {"ocean"=>"blue"},
  {"pumpkin"=>"orange"}
]
```

How can I iterate the colors array to check if the values are present in the object's hash value as well, and yield this result?

```
[["sun","yellow"], ["sky","blue"], ["ocean","blue"], ["pumpkin","orange"]]
```

Comment: I want to return the objects whose values are included in the colors array.

Comment: I have trouble understanding, can you explain more clearly your goal?

Comment: mee too. Didn't get the logic. Can you elaborate more and fix the `objects` array, so we can help you.

Comment: `objects` is not a valid Ruby object. Please correct and in future confirm your code is correct before posting.

Comment: So you want to return `ocean => blue` as well? Since blue is in colors..

Comment: @UlysseBN right, I forgot that part. Sorry, it's a little late where I am.

Comment: @olafsadventures np, check my answer and tell me if this solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To select items from an object, use `array#select` method:

```
elements.select{|el|colors.flatten.include? el.values[0]} # => [{"sun"=>"yellow"}, {"sky"=>"blue"}, {"ocean"=>"blue"}]
```

Let me break this code for you:

1. `elements.select` iterate over your array
2. `flatten` just flatten your colors array: `[['a', 'b'], 'c'].flatten` gives you `['a', 'b', 'c']`
3. `array#include? i` returns true if your value is in the array

Then you can convert it to an array of `[key, value]` array doing

```
filtered_elements.map(&:to_a)
```

This is calls `object#to_a` method on every object of your array

Comment: I dumped this in IRB and got an empty hash.

Comment: @olafsadventures oups, i found the mistake. Edited, now working (I checked). You may need to replace `===` with `.include?`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

```
objects =[{ "sun"=>"yellow" }, { "sky"=>"blue" },
          { "ocean"=>"blue" }, { "pumpkin"=>"orange" }]
```

and that each element of `objects` is to be retained and converted to a flattened array if the single value is an element of one of the elements of `colors`, where

```
colors =[["blue", "red", "green"], ["yellow", "red", "green"],  ["orange", "red"]]
```

One can write the following.

```
ucolors = colors.flatten.uniq
  #=> ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "orange"] 
objects.flat_map(&:to_a).select { |_,c| ucolors.include? c }
  #=> [["sun", "yellow"], ["sky", "blue"], ["ocean", "blue"], ["pumpkin", "orange"]]
```

Note

```
objects.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [["sun", "yellow"], ["sky", "blue"], ["ocean", "blue"], ["pumpkin", "orange"]]
```

A second example (with `objects` unchanged):

```
colors =[["blue", "red", "green"], ["pink", "red", "green"],  ["orange", "red"]]
ucolors = colors.flatten.uniq
  #=> ["blue", "red", "green", "pink", "orange"] 
objects.flat_map(&:to_a).select { |_,c| ucolors.include? c }
  #=> [["sky", "blue"], ["ocean", "blue"], ["pumpkin", "orange"]]
```

Comment: @olafsadventures of course it worked, but if it worked, you **are obliged** to **mark this answer as correct**.

Comment: Olaf, pay no attention to Mudsie's instruction. He's well-meaning but gets carried away at times. You should be in no rush to select an answer. If, after a reasonable amount of time, at least one answer is helpful, then select the one you find to be most helpful.